# Rails Throws Error When Using redirect_to :back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, undefined

Whenever I use:

```
redirect_to :back
```

in my Rails controllers, I get the following error:

> undefined method `object_url' for SubmissionController:0xb7a37764

I'll paste the application trace below as well:

> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/polymorphic_routes.rb:112:in
>   `__send__'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/polymorphic_routes.rb:112:in`
>   polymorphic_url'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:628:in
>   `url_for'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1085:in`
>   redirect_to'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1080:in
>   `redirect_to'
>
> app/controllers/submission_controller.rb:38:in
>   `show'

I'm pretty sure its not a syntax error, but something deeper. Maybe a problem occurred during an update or something. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using "redirect_to" in this case, just use ":back".
For example:

is shorthand for the JavaScript utility obtaining the previous URL in your history.